# Remove unused factor levels from a ggplot bar plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, factors

I want to do the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834382/ggplot2-keep-unused-levels-barplot), and sort of the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002627/ggplot2-0-9-0-automatically-dropping-unused-factor-levels-from-plot-legend), though that's about legends, not the plot itself.

The other SO questions seem to be asking about how to *keep* unused factor levels. I'd actually like mine removed. I have several name variables and several columns (wide format) of variable attributes that I'm using to create numerous bar plots. Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(name=c("A","B","C"), var1=c(1,NA,2),var2=c(3,4,5))
ggplot(df, aes(x=name,y=var1)) + geom_bar()
```

I get this:

[image]

I'd like only the names that have corresponding var<sub>n</sub>'s show up in my bar plot (as in, there would be no empty space for B).

Reusing the base plot code will be quite easy if I can simply change my output file name and `y=var` bit. I'd like not have to subset my data frame just to use droplevels on the result for each plot if possible!

---

**Update based on the `na.omit()` suggestion**

Consider a revised data set:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(name=c("A","B","C"), var1=c(1,NA,2),var2=c(3,4,5), var3=c(NA,6,7))
ggplot(df, aes(x=name,y=var1)) + geom_bar()
```

I need to use `na.omit()` for plotting `var1` because there's an NA present. But since na.omit makes sure values are present for *all columns*, the plot removes `A` as well since it has an NA in `var3`. This is more analogous to my data. I have 15 total responses with NAs peppered about. I only want to remove factor levels that don't have values for the *current* plotted y vector, not that have NAs in *any* vector in the whole data frame.

Comment: Why do you need have a data-frame to begin with, when you're actually just plotting one row of it? If you didn't have the data frame (and, rather, had just a list/vector) you could just drop the NA fields).

Comment: @TiloWiklund: I'm an R novice, so feel free to suggest an alternative. I'm plotting a column of names against numerous different columns of data for a series of plots. Some columns are incomplete, some aren't. The incomplete ones are analogous to the above and leave gaps which I don't want since I only need to compare the variables that actually have data associated with them for that particular measured response. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can also simply drop rows by setting a condition on only that column: `ggplot(df[!is.na(df$var1),], aes(x=name,y=var1)) + geom_bar()`.

Comment: @joran: this seems quite similar to Tilo's solution below, though a bit simpler than passing two vector names. Regardless of the tweak on omitting na's, I guess the real lesson learned is that there's no way to do this automatically from ggplot.

Comment: @TiloWiklund `ggplot()` expects a data frame as it's first argument. And anyway, isn;t he plotting two rows of it, one a factor (`name`) the other a numeric (`var1`)? Hendy needs to pass both variables otherwise how does `ggplot()` know to plot the values as two bars not a numeric vector of data?

Comment: @GavinSimpson true, bad wording on my part. I should have said he used a fixed and finite number of columns.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One easy options is to use `na.omit()` on your data frame `df` to remove those rows with `NA`

```
ggplot(na.omit(df), aes(x=name,y=var1)) + geom_bar()
```

Given your update, the following

```
ggplot(df[!is.na(df$var1), ], aes(x=name,y=var1)) + geom_bar()
```

works OK and only considers `NA` in `Var1`. Given that you are only plotting `name` and `Var`, apply `na.omit()` to a data frame containing only those variables

```
ggplot(na.omit(df[, c("name", "var1")]), aes(x=name,y=var1)) + geom_bar()
```

Comment: This is great and very easy. My actual data set must be missing one or more values from numerous columns as applying `na.omit` leaves me with a data frame with no rows... Any other suggestions?

Comment: It would have been helpful to know that initially. See my updated Answer.

Comment: I would have liked to specify that as well. Not knowing what solution would come up, I didn't realize that would be an issue. Honestly, I expected there to be a ggplot option to drop things. Given that people want to *keep* unused levels in the linked questions and are able to specify `drop=FALSE`, I kind of wondered why `drop=T` wouldn't do exactly what I wanted! Thanks for the updated answer.

Comment: @Hendy The level `B` is not unused in your example. It is very much used as it is present in the data. The `NA` is just as valid a data point as any other value as far as R is concerned. A truly unused level would be the `B` in `A <- factor(c("a","c"), levels = c("a","b","c"))`. In `A`, the level `b` is not present in the data.

Comment: Sure, technically, I suppose. From my perspective, I have prototypes and numerous measured test results. There is no data at the intersection of prototype `B` and test method `var1`. My data frame is composed of a column of prototype names and columns of test data. Wide format. "Truly unused levels" are only possible in long, right?

Comment: You are missing the point that there *is* data at the intersection of `B` and `var1`; we just don't have the value of that data available to us. Re wide vs long, again that is not strictly correct; for example, if we do `df[!is.na(df$var1), ]` the variable `name` in the resulting data frame *is* a factor with the same levels as the full data set and hence it now does have a truly un-used level, that of `B`. Un-used levels can crop up in any factor.

Comment: Put another way, forget about `var1` as that has nothing to do with the un-used level. If there are no elements of a factor that correspond to one or more levels of the factor then those levels are considered un-used. This is independent of the data structure or format.

Comment: I guess my point was that if my data was in long format with vectors `name`, `var` and `value`, I could create a "truly unused factor" without massaging data with `!is.na`. That's not possible in my current data arrangement, correct? (With the above, I have no choice but to have a "blank" at the intersection of `name` and `var1`. In long form I just wouldn't have a row in which `name=B`, `var=1`.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that, when plotting, you're using only two columns of your data frame, meaning that, rather than passing your whole data.frame you could take the relevant columns `x[,c("name", "var1")]` apply na.omit to remove the unwanted rows (as Gavin Simpson suggests) `na.omit(x[,c("name", "var1")])` and then plot this data.

My R/ggplot is quite rusty, and I realise that there are probably cleaner ways to achieve this.

Comment: Didn't realize I could do that from within ggplot, but it now seems obvious. This definitely works. It would be great if there was an equivalent to `drop=T` or `scale="free"` as I'll have to tweak all of my plot functions this way. Shouldn't b too bad and I'll just use `dat[, c(1,n)]` so that I can just iterate through each without much hassle. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A lot of time has passed since this question was originally asked. In 2021 if I was handling this I would use something like:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(name=c("A","B","C"), var1=c(1,NA,2),var2=c(3,4,5))

df %>% 
  drop_na(var1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, var1)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is awesome! I think there are *a lot* of questions on SO like this. I just did something similar to another question, where all of the answers now seemed fiddly and tedious vs. `dplyr`. Thanks for taking the time to `modernize()`  :)