# Keep group on axis but remove NA value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi suppose I have a dataframe like this.

```
df = data.frame ( 
    sample= c("a","b","c","d"),
    type = c("orange", "apple","carrots", NA)
    )
```

What I want is to keep d in the x-axis but because the type is NA I want to be just an empty space there. Curently because of the NA ggplot literally creates a group call NA.

```
ggplot(data=df, 
       aes(x=sample, y= type , na.rm = TRUE ) )+ 
    geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(type)   ), size = 20, na.rm = TRUE) +
    xlab("") + ylab("")
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002627/ggplot2-0-9-0-automatically-dropping-unused-factor-levels-from-plot-legend

Comment: You don't want to omit the rows where NA appear?

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro omit NA but keep group d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
ggplot(data=subset(df,!is.na(type)), 
       aes(x=sample, y= type) )+ 
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(type)   ), size = 20, na.rm = TRUE) +
  xlab("") + ylab("")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c('a','b','c','d'))
```

Output:

[image]

Or this (althought it can not be very optimal invoking the data in the function):

```
#Plot 2
ggplot(data=subset(df,!is.na(type)), 
       aes(x=sample, y= type) )+ 
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(type)   ), size = 20, na.rm = TRUE) +
  xlab("") + ylab("")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(df$sample))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the last example is perfect!  Very clever, I didn't think about just adding into the x-axis manually.

Comment: @Ahdee Yeah, it is a trick to get the plot as you want. I hope that was helpful for you!

Answer (score 2):

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = sample, y = type)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(type)), size = 20) +
    scale_colour_discrete(na.value = "transparent")
```

Check `scale_colour_discrete(na.translate = FALSE)` as well

Comment: Thanks @d.b  that is clever, however, the issue with this is that the NA row is still there.

Answer (score 0):

In your example where there is only NA value for group d it'll remove it, but if in your real dataset there are other observations for d `na.omit(df)` won't remove it

```
df = data.frame ( 
  sample= c("a","b","c","d", "d"),
  type = c("orange", "apple","carrots", NA, "orange"))
df = na.omit(df)
```

Then running your ggplot code:

[image]